# Payment to Sagepay not submitting

Tags: cartthrob, sagepay

We have a multi-step checkout, with SagePay Europe Direct as the default payment gateway.

When it comes to inputting your card details on the site and submitting, you get redirected back to the enter payment details page. There are no errors coming up and the order isn't being processed in the CP either.

We have set up Sagepay test area and added our IP address for doing test transactions. Plus I've checked we are using the right SagePay test details.

We are using the update_cart_form for collecting billing and shipping details then using checkout_form on the final step for collecting payment details.

Some help would be great as we I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: What does Sage Pay report on the transaction? Does it succeed or fail? Is the transaction data being submitted correctly?